Is there a full comic of the crab-like alien explorers I remember?
I remember some years ago seeing a few images from a comic project about a crab-like people and their alien technology posted on the web. I remember two images in particular: the first showed their mobile research base, a two-storey mobile water tank with living quarters and more researchey areas, in a dry environment. The second one showed a technological device, something like a pocket computer maybe. The device has a biological component, and the power “cord” had shaped tube connectors for delivering nutrients to the device and for waste leaving it. The technology image looked more sketchy than the base, which was not photo-realistic but have-drawn and probably inked and included quite a lot of details. I have done an image search for crab-like aliens, but all that tells me is that most crab-like aliens are imagined much more humanoid than these people.
Can anyone identify the comic project based on this description? Did this turn into a full comic which I might be able to read somewhere?
